# Track camera position with RealityKit

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

How can you track the position of the camera using RealityKit? Several examples are using SceneKit, but I found none using RealityKit. I need a function such as:

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
    // Do something with the new transform
    let currentTransform = frame.camera.transform
    doSomething(with: currentTransform)
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Using ARView Camera Transform:**

You can access the ARView Camera Transform using the following method:

```
var cameraTransform: Transform
```

> The transform of the currently active camera.

So assuming your `ARView` was called `arView` you could access the `Transform` like so:

```
let cameraTransform = arView.cameraTransform
```

A more useful implementation however would be to enable your `ARView` to observe `SceneEvents.Update`by making use of the following:

```
subscribe(to:on:_:)

func subscribe<E>(to event: E.Type, on sourceObject: EventSource? = nil, _ handler: @escaping (E) -> Void) -> Cancellable where E : Event
```

Which means you would have an observer of any:

> event triggered once per frame interval that you can use to execute
>   custom logic for each frame.

To do that you would:
Firstly import the `Combine` Framework.

You would then create a `Cancellable` variable:

```
var sceneObserver: Cancellable!
```

Then in `ViewDidLoad` add something like the following:

```
sceneObserver = arView.scene.subscribe(to: SceneEvents.Update.self) { [unowned self] in self.updateScene(on: $0) }
```

Whereby each update calls the following:

```
/// Callback For ARView Update Events
/// - Parameter event: SceneEvents.Update
func updateScene(on event: SceneEvents.Update) {

  print(arView.cameraTransform)

}
```

**Using ARSessionDelegate:**

Alternatively you can access the `ARCamera` from within `RealityKit` by subscribing to the `ARSessionDelegate` e.g:

```
arView.session.delegate = self
```

And then registering for the following callback:

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame)
```

Whereby a working example would look something like this:

```
extension ViewController: ARSessionDelegate {

  func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {

    guard let arCamera = session.currentFrame?.camera else { return }
    print("""
      ARCamera Transform = \(arCamera.transform)
      ARCamera ProjectionMatrix = \(arCamera.projectionMatrix)
      ARCamera EulerAngles = \(arCamera.eulerAngles)
      """)

  }

}
```

Hope it points you in the right direction.

Comment: Great answer as always! What would be the benefits to subscribe to updates via Combine? I'm used to work with the session delegates in SceneKit and would also  prefer to do so in RealityKit unless Combine brings benefits ?